How to update Business Phone on Admins with Power Automate
I am running a workflow that pulls employee information from a spreadsheet and fills in their contact data and organization data. Everything runs fine except when it gets to updating the business numbers of other Admins in EntraAD. I get
"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
I have built out the app registration with the appropriate permissions to make changes to user accounts.
Im using a post HTTP to make the access token, Parse JSON, Then using a PATCH HTTP with the Authorization Bearer(AccessToken)
All users run fine except when it gets to admins I get the above error.
I have changed the permissions on both the Admin account attached to the workflow and the App registration to no success.

Might be worth raising with Microsoft, it sounds like you know what you're doing and have tried quite a few things.

The Entra app you have registered must be assigned to the privileged authentication administrator role or to the global administrator role to be able to update business phone of admins.

Thank you, I was able to get it working by setting up a custom role and assigning the correct permissions to that, that adding the app registration to the role.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thank you, I was able to get it working by setting up a custom role and assigning the correct role permissions (which were ContactInfo, Basic, and Extension Properties). I then added the app registration to that role and was able to successfully update the business phones for admins.
